# App Engine deployed app doesn't receive emails

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

My App Engine app receives emails in the developement server, not when deployed.

In **app.yaml** I have:

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: incoming_email.app
  login: admin

inbound_services:
- mail
```

In **incoming_email.py** I have:

```
class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):
        logging.info("Received a message from ""%s"" to ""%s""" % 
                     (mail_message.sender, mail_message.to))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)
```

In the developer server it works as expected:

- I click on **Inbound Mail**
- Set From=abc@def.ghi, To=abc@my-app-id.appspot.com, Subject=some, Object=thing
- Click **Send**
- => It says "Request succeeded!"
- => In the log I read `[...]"incoming_email.py:12] Received a message from abc@def.ghi to abc@my-app-id.appspot.com"`.

In the deployed application it doesn't work:

- In the dashboard **Application Settings** the **Configured Services** section shows **Incoming Email**
- In the dashboard there is no **Inbound Mail** item or anything similar
- I send an email from my gmail account to the same abc@my-app-id.appspot.com address
- => The log file doesn't show anything
- => My gmail account receives a bounce

If I understand [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail), the app should receive any email sent to any my-app-id.appspot.com address, as long as this is the mapping: `- url: /_ah/mail/.+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please send the email to `string@appid.appspotmail.com` for deployed application and check if the email is received.

For e.g. if your APP ID is `myapp`, then send the email to say `abc@myapp.appspotmail.com`

The above format is documented at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail

Comment: I missed **mail** at the end of **appspotmail.com** (and that's how to miss a word and waste 3 hours!!!)